# TeamCity - Re-running a specific build step

Tags: c#, teamcity

For arguments sake if you've configured 3 builds steps and you want to re-run the 3rd step in isolation (not run the prior 2 steps), how would you achieve this?

Comment: ... you can't do that with just TeamCity, TeamCity will always run all the steps in sequence. What you *can* do is make something that makes the first two steps do nothing, but this seems like a brittle build configuration. What're you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The possibility to run only a specific build step would be extremely usable when setting up and testing a new build step. 

Right now I have some trouble with a new last build step that does something fairly trivial - just copying a number of files. Every time I want to test a modification to that step, I have to run a complete build with the 21 preceding build steps, taking something like 5 minutes.

IMO this is one of the few PITAs in an otherwise great software.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, not possible....unless you temporarily disable the earlier steps in admin, and run the build again.

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Configuring+Build+Steps

Comment: Yep, was the only way to achieve what I wanted

Answer (score 2):

You could split your 3 build steps into 2 build configurations with a snapshot dependency between the two. The first build configuration would contain the first two build steps. The dependency should be set to `'Run build on the same agent'` and `'Do not run new build if there is a suitable one'`. This will chain the two configurations together, but will optionally allow you to just run the second configuration if nothing has changed in source.

Depending on your setup this may or may not be a suitable solution. This could work ok if your third build step is running some tests which just need to be rerun without recompiling the code.