# How to configure Teamcity to ignore some tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, teamcity

There is a way to configure Teamcity to ignore some tests? I need to run these tests only locally, when they are running in Teamcity, must be ignored.

I'm using nunit.

This could be a directive, attribute, etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618225/teamcity-re-running-a-specific-build-step

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this by adding test categories to your tests.

```
[Category("LocalOnly")]
[Test]
public void MyLocalTest()
{
    // Code omitted for brevity
}
```

You can then add that category to the NUnit runner's 'NUnit categories exclude:' field in the TeamCity build step.

```
NUnit categories exclude: LocalOnly
```

[image: The TeamCity NUnit ignore category field]

Comment: For `MSTest` how to exclude tests in a specific `[TestCategory]` ?

Answer (score 5):

TeamCity 9.1 [supports](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/NUnit) NUnit 3 and it opens [many other possibilities](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/wiki/Console-Command-Line) to select tests for executing or filter them out. I would recommend to use `--where=EXPRESSION` which allows to use [Test Selection Language](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/wiki/Test-Selection-Language). Now you can use even regular expressions to specify tests you want to run or exclude.

**Examples**

Do you want to exclude only one test?

```
--where="method != 'TestName'"
```

Do you want to exclude only one test? Don't remember the name exactly but something with "BuggyMethod" (`~` means that a regular expression is involved):

```
--where="method !~ 'BuggyMethod'"
```

Run all tests defined in one class:

```
--where="class == 'My.Namespace.ClassName'"
```

Forget the full namespace? It's not a problem anymore - use a regular expression:

```
--where="class =~ 'ClassName'"
```

You can also combine these expressions to achieve a desired effect. Run all tests for the class but exlude all methods which contain "BuggyMethod":

```
--where="class =~ 'ClassName' and method !~ 'BuggyMethod'"
```

This approach is much more flexible and avoids any modifications of your code. I don't see a point to use categories anymore, unless your tests are classified using categories.