# MSTest ignore test by environment to avoid running in TeamCity

Tags: visual-studio, teamcity, mstest

Visual Studio 2019 16.4.1
ASP.NET Core 3.1
MSTest v1.3.2 v2.0.0
TeamCity 2019.1.2 (build 66342)

I have an integration-test that I would like to be included when I run my test suite locally in Visual Studio but be excluded when run under my integration-tests build step in my TeamCity pipeline.

```
[Ignore] // I need this ignore to only apply when run in TeamCity
[TestMethod]
public void MyTest()
{
}
```

Perhaps it's possible to make the `[Ignore]` conditional on `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` system environment variable ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure Teamcity to ignore some tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33876192/how-to-configure-teamcity-to-ignore-some-tests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you pass a filter to the tests when running them on TeamCity? Using the [example from the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/selective-unit-tests#mstest):

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace MSTestNamespace
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestCategory("CategoryA")]
        [Priority(1)]
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
        }

        [Priority(2)]
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod2()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

`dotnet test --filter TestCategory=CategoryA`

Runs tests that are annotated with `[TestCategory("CategoryA")]`.

In your example, CategoryA would be replaced with a label to indicate they are integration tests.